# How do I center my page while making my header take the full width of the browser window?

Tags: css, header, width, center

I've seen tons of demos on the web about how "simple" it is to center the content on your page. I figured out how to make my header take up the entire width of the browser window however whenever I try to center my content all my browsers extend the width of the page, so I end up having a horizontal scrollbar. The other problem is my header is a different color than the rest of my browser so when I make changes to the body sometimes it changes the width of the header so that the color doesn't fill the window. This website is a great example of what I am trying to achieve http://carlodiego.businesscatalyst.com/

I also want my header to have overflow: none; so that if someone makes the browser window smaller the header begins to disappear. I've been working on this for hours a regardless what I do something else breaks. Below is my code. Sorry but it's lengthy.

```
<body>
<header>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="fixed">
            <div id="menu-container">
                <ul id="navigationMenu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="normalMenu">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="normalMenu">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="normalMenu">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="normalMenu">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="title">
            <h1>Alex</h1>
            <h1 id="last">Chaparro</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

</header>

        <div id="background">

        <div id="front-end">
           <h1>Front-End <br> Developer</h1>
        </div>
        <div id=content>

            <h1 class="heading">About</h1>
            <p>content</p>

            <h2>Currently Using</h2>
            <p>More Content...</p>

            <h2>Currently Following</h2>
            <p>Chris Mills | David Sawyer Mcfarland | Phil Thompson </p>

            <h1 class="heading">Work</h1>

        </div>
      </div>
</div>
</body>


body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: 'optimusprincepssemiboldRg';
    background: #fafafa;

    background-color: #eeeeee;
    }



article, aside, audio, canvas, datalist, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, video {
    display: block;
}

#title {
    font-family: 'optimusprincepssemiboldRg';
    color: black;
}

#last {
    font-size: 400%;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#menu-container {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 420px;
    white-space: nowrap; /* stops text from wrapping */
    overflow: hidden;
}

#background {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
}

#front-end {
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 200%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.heading {
    font-size: 300%;
}

#fixed {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /*This stops the color from going away*/
    background-color: #cee3ee;
}

#wrapper {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
```

Comment: By "browser" I suppose you mean the viewport? The browser is a software. Not something you see on a site. And by centering, do you mean vertical or horizontal centering?

Comment: Show your code attempt so we have something to "fix".  We're not going to write a page from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to have a `header` and `main` divs. and make them `absolute` positioned.
and use `margin:0px auto;` for centering the main.

something like this http://jsfiddle.net/WAR4r/

Comment: that has put me in the right direction. When you minimize the page the color on top does not take the full-width.  All you above I'm sorry if I didn't make my question more clear. I didn't put my code out there because I thought it was lengthy will do next time.

Comment: what do you mean the color on top? if you mean the header, yes it takes the whole width regardless of the size of the page.

Comment: Actually btevfik if you try the code your wrote change header css to header { text-align: right; and add a background color. Then make the window smaller a horizontal scrollbar comes up and if you move it right you will see that the color is no longer there. How can I avoid that?

Comment: i dont see any problem here.

Comment: No I got rid of the borders, made the .main 960px, and put some content in the header. If you make your browser window a little bit smaller a horizontal scrollbar will come up and if you scroll right you'll see that the red is gone and the background is white.

Comment: ah i see. its because the main has a fixed width. if you dont want, then you need to make main width a percentage. %50 for example.