# Centered body with a fixed width 'stationary' header

Tags: css

My question is almost identical to part of this question, yet it did not lead me to a solution. [How do I center my page while making my header take the full width of the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456945/how-do-i-center-my-page-while-making-my-header-take-the-full-width-of-the-browse)

Using the following css snippet my page is perfectly centered in the viewport as the browser window changes size, however I want the header image to remain in the same position, flush against the left hand side of the viewport, no matter what the viewport window width is.

```
#page{
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1024px;
}


 #header {width: 1200px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your #header outside your #page and set margin-left and margin-right to auto

Comment: I had a horrble feeling that was teh solution, but hoped I coudl avoid it.  I'm not good at moving divs and creating new ones in Drupal.

However I gave it a go and I think I did it.  

For anyone in a similar situation, I found this tutorial helpful, plus other online help http://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-theming-basics-drupal-7

Thank you Throrin.